# Contents of APK (Android Package)

Tags: android, apk, google-play

Do APK's have any sort of user specific metadata? I mean does it include information about the publisher like the device MAC on which the publisher built on or OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every APK file contains an [Android App Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) in binary XML form. In this file a publisher contains can place info about the minimum/maximum API level (Android version) and restrict the App to certain device types (e.g. tablets).

You will not find information about the compiling computer there. They are not relevant for Android.

Comment: Of course they are not relevant for Android, but might be interesting data for Google? security reasons maybe?

Comment: No, for security the code you write and the platform it runs on is relevant. The compiler and the OS it runs on is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

By default there is no user specific info attached to an android application.

However, you need to add the publisher specific data before releasing, thats done by creating your build with a Publisher-Key. This key should be created using the user specific information(Company name etc).